# jquery trigger an event

Tags: jquery, events

I have an ajax script executed using jquery when an input text field is changed using keyup. This part works fine. However, I also want to trigger this same keyup event when the form autoloads with some text in this input text field.

I'm auto-loading the form text field by using php to populate the form from the url (get request).

My HTML code:

```
<input id="code" name="code" type="text" />
```

My JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  // doesn't work
  // i want to execute the code in the function specified within $('#code').keyup(function () {} below. nothing happens here.
  if ($('#code').val() != '') {
    $('#code').trigger('keyup');
  }

  // works fine
  $('#code').keyup(function () {
   // function code
  }
}
```

Not sure if I'm doing this right. Would appreciate if anyone could help me out on this. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to trigger `keyup` (either with `$('#code').trigger('keyup')` or `$('#code').keyup()`), **after** binding the event handler, not before.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#code').keyup(function () {
        // function code
    }

    if ($('#code').val() != '') {
        $('#code').trigger('keyup');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I actually realised this was the case a few minutes ago. Came on to the website again to say that I've resolved it, but realised you have already saw the problem. Thanks again! I actually spent a good 3 hours trying to figure this out. :S

Answer (score 1):

have you tried just calling `.keyup()` instead of `.trigger('keyup')`?

another thing you could do is abstract the code you want to call into another function and call that instead of triggering a click:

```
$('#code').keyup(myFunction);
```

Comment: Hi Jason, that was exactly what I was trying to do, by moving the code into a function and calling it from there. Needless to say, I encountered other problems, like how do I make sure "this" within the function was referring to $('#code'). Would declaring var code = $('#code') in the function resolve that problem? Thanks anyway! =)

Comment: Sorry Jason, would have specified yours as the correct answer but K Prime's was clearer for a beginner like me. :) Thanks!